# Question about Quran createdness (kalam al-nafsi and kalam al-lafdhi)

Tags: quran, sunnah, sunni, islamic-philosophy, theology

Kalam Nafsi is the eternal speech of Allah, while Kalam Lafdhi refers to the created speech of Allah within time and space. Ibn Hajar, writing about the opponents of Kalam Lafdhi, states that some went so far as to affirm the uncreatedness of the paper and ink by which the Qur'an was written:

> As for Bukhārī, he was tried by those who said ‘The voices of the
> slaves (of Allah) are uncreated’ until some of them went overboard and
> said, “**The same goes for the ink and the paper after being written (i.e.
> they are also uncreated**).” وأما البخاري، فابتلي بمن يقول: أصوات العباد غير مخلوقة، حتى بالغ بعضهم فقال: والمداد والورق بعد الكتابة فكان أكثر كلامه في الرد عليهم ([Source](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/45686/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A2%D9%86-%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%BA%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D9%85%D8%AE%D9%84%D9%88%D9%82))

Is this still an acceptable position within Sunni Islam? Are there still scholars who hold this position? Further reading and sources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share a source of the definition of the terms Kalam nafsi and Kalam lafdhi.